# Unable to render Django Rest Framework Errors on React JS page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

ReactJS newbie here.
I'm working on a ReactJS project with Django Backend. I'm facing an issue where I send user signup info to django api and it returns error as follows. (Note that when Data is correct, API end point works fine. And in case of error, generic error message i.e. error code 400 is displayed without any issue)

```
{
"username": [
    "A user with that username already exists."
],
"email": [
    "This field must be unique."
]
```

}

This is what I send from my action.js

```
catch (error) {

    dispatch({
        type: USER_REGISTER_FAIL,
        payload: error.response.data})
}
```

When I try to iterate the error, following error id displayed

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

**typeof(error)** shows this is an object.
And when I see it in console.log, there are two arrays in the object. each containing one element (i.e. username and email, respectively).

```
{username: Array(1), email: Array(1)}
```

I want to render errors in their corresponding fields. i.e. username error must be displayed above username input field and so on. How do I iterate the object so I may get the right message for the respective input?

Thanks to all genius minds out there.

Comment: When you say 'When I try to iterate the error', what do you mean specifically in code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @WillWalsh
I'm using array.map function. I have used this function before too. I don't know why it is not working in this scenario

Comment: So for example, you store the return from Django in `error` and use `error.map`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: `.map` can only be run on an array. If `error` is an object, you have to get the values another way.